ValueError: cannot reshape array of size X into shape (Y, Z, ...) in convolution layer output in Python
Description:
I'm implementing a forward pass for a convolutional layer in Python. The convolution appears to run, but when reshaping the output for visualization in the test script, I get the error:
ValueError:
 cannot reshape array of size X into shape (Y, Z, ...)
Error Trace:

ValueError:
 cannot reshape array of size 30 into shape (3, 5, 5)
This occurs when the test script attempts to reshape the convolution output data into the expected format in the display_results() function.

I cannot modify the test script (including the display_results() function), which expects the convolution output to be of a certain shape.
Specifically, the output needs to be reshaped to (output['channel'], output['height'], output['width']). However, the number of elements in the array doesn't match the expected size.
Convolution Layer Function:
Here’s the relevant part of my conv_layer_forward() function:
def conv_layer_forward(input_data, layer, param):
    h_in = input_data['height']
    w_in = input_data['width']
    c = input_data['channel']
    batch_size = input_data['batch_size']
    k = layer['k']  # kernel size
    pad = layer['pad']  # padding
    stride = layer['stride']  # stride
    num = layer['num']  # number of filters (output channels)

    h_out = (h_in + 2 * pad - k) // stride + 1
    w_out = (w_in + 2 * pad - k) // stride + 1

    output = {
        'height': h_out,
        'width': w_out,
        'channel': num,
        'batch_size': batch_size,
        'data': np.zeros((batch_size, h_out, w_out, num))
    }

    try:
        # Perform convolution using im2col (details omitted)
        input_cols = im2col_conv_batch(input_data['data'], k, pad, stride)
        W_cols = param['w'].reshape(num, -1)
        conv_result = np.dot(W_cols, input_cols)
        conv_result += param['b'].reshape(-1, 1)

        conv_result = conv_result.reshape(num, h_out, w_out, batch_size)
        output['data'] = np.transpose(conv_result, (3, 1, 2, 0))  # Shape: (batch_size, h_out, w_out, num)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during convolution: {str(e)}")
    
    return output


Test Script (I CANNOT MODIFY):
The test script runs several tests and calls the conv_layer_forward() function, then tries to visualize the output. Here's the part where the error occurs:img1 = output['data'][:,batch].reshape(output['channel'], output['height'], output['width'])
Expected Behavior:
The output data should be of shape (batch_size, h_out, w_out, num) and reshaped into (num, h_out, w_out) for each batch during visualization.
Problem:
The error indicates that the size of the array doesn't match the expected shape when reshaped. The number of elements in output['data'][:,batch] does not match the required shape (output['channel'], output['height'], output['width']). Specifically, it seems like the convolution output is smaller than expected.
Question:
How can I fix my conv_layer_forward() function to ensure that the output data matches the expected shape and size required by the test script? Is there something wrong with how I calculate or reshape the convolution result?
Notes:
I cannot modify the test script or display_results().
The padding, stride, and kernel size seem to be correct based on the provided input dimensions.
The output dimensions are calculated using the standard convolution formula.
